# Real Analysis Sequence convergence help

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $\{ y_n \}$ is a sequence of real numbers. Then $y_n$ approaches infinity as $n$ approaches infinity means that for every $M$ in the real numbers, there exists $N$ in the integers such that 
$n\geq N$ implies $y_n > M$

Suppose that $x_n>0$ for all $n$ and $x_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Prove that $\frac{1}{x_n}$ approaches infinity as $n$ approaches infinity

Comment: What definition are you using for the limit as it goes to $0$?

Comment: the same as {y_n}

Comment: so $\epsilon-N$ proof? If $n>N$ then $x_n<\epsilon$?

Comment: yes! how do we go about doing this. my study group has been stuck on it for a while

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $x_n<\epsilon$ so $\frac{1}{x_n} > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ for all $n$ we can choose $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small so $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ is arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $x_n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ implies that for any $k$ an integer, there exists $N_k$ such that for all $n\geq N_k$, $x_n < \frac{1}{k}$, i.e. $k< \frac{1}{x_n}$.  First, why is this true? And second, this immediately implies what you are trying to prove, do you see why?